# IntrinsicHeight inside a Stack

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a widget tree that has a variable height.

I need to create another widget that will be on top of it under certain circumstances.

I need this other widget to take up the full height of the stack, depending on the first widget's height.

So it goes like this:

```
Stack(
  children[
    Widget2(),
    SomeVariableHeighWidget1()
  ],
)
```

I've tried wrapping Widget2 in `IntrinsicHeight`, for example

```
Widget2 = IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.green,
  ),
),
```

but I see nothing. If I set a fixed height to the Container I can see it, and it does take up the full width, but I can't get it to take up the full height. I also tried `Expanded` but it is incorrect use of parent data widget.

Thank you

Comment: maybe post an image of what your stack should look like

Comment: @pskink it is a widget4 that has a flexible size, and on top of it stacked, another widget that would cover the first one completely, so the image of the stack in the case above is widget2 a green rectangle that takes up the whole space matching the width and height of widget1 and covering it

Comment: check `CustomMultiChildLayout`

Comment: but actually you could also use `Widget2(child: SomeVariableHeighWidget1())`

Comment: @pskink no I can't because they display at different times. Widget1 displays all the time. I could conditionally wrap it maybe, I think it may be a good idea. Thank you. The thing is one of the widgets is DropzoneView that doesn't take children, but there is another library that does

Comment: I ended up using https://pub.dev/documentation/measured_size/latest/ to measure widget1 and apply the height to widget 2

Comment: @pskink is there a simple way to get the size of a widget (without this library)? All answers I find are too complicated for me

Comment: `CustomMultiChildLayout`

Comment: Thank you ! I will try this out... :)